# Find the volume solid bounded by surfaces $xy$, $z = 2(x^2+y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2 = 2y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

> Find the volume solid bounded by surfaces $xy$, $z = 2(x^2+y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2 = 2y$.

I've tried to simply transform to cylindrical coordinates, and my answer was $6 \pi$. But the correct answer shows $3 \pi$. Where is my mistake?

$z = 0$ - ($xy$ plane) until $z = 2 r^2$ (paraboloid);

$r = 2 \sin \phi$;

$V = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\phi}\int_{0}^{2r^2}\,dz\,rdr\,d\phi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the graph of $r = 2\sin \phi$ for $\phi \in [\pi,2\pi]$ overlaps with that for $\phi \in [0,\pi]$,

[image: graph of r = 2 sin phi]
graph from [spark notes](http://img.sparknotes.com/figures/A/a51f3a0c94362c4c588802bc84a399d6/polargraph.gif)

the upper limit for $\phi$ should be $\pi$ instead of $2 \pi$.

\begin{align}
V &= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\phi}\int_{0}^{2r^2}\,dz\,rdr\,d\phi \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin\phi}2r^3 dr\,d\phi \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(2 \sin \phi)^4}{2} \,d\phi \\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^4 \phi \,d\phi \\
&= 16 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^4 \phi \,d\phi \quad (\text{symmetry of sine}: \sin\left(\frac\pi2+\phi\right) = \sin\left(\frac\pi2-\phi\right)) \\
&= 16 \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 1}{4 \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \quad \text{(Wallis' formula)} \\
&= 3\pi
\end{align}

Comment: Thank u so much for clarifier the question and add more information about the integral resolution in the end (idk these wallis method). Nice tool!